# Back-Propagation of y = x / sum(x, dim=0) where size of tensor x is (H,W)

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

Q1.

I'm trying to make my custom autograd function with pytorch.

But I had a problem with making analytical back propagation with  y = x / sum(x, dim=0)

where size of tensor x is (Height, Width) (x is 2-dimensional).

Here's my code

```
class MyFunc(torch.autograd.Function):
@staticmethod
def forward(ctx, input):
  ctx.save_for_backward(input)
  input = input / torch.sum(input, dim=0)

  return input

@staticmethod
def backward(ctx, grad_output):
  input = ctx.saved_tensors[0]
  H, W = input.size()
  sum = torch.sum(input, dim=0)
  grad_input = grad_output * (1/sum - input*1/sum**2)

  return grad_input
```

I used (torch.autograd import) gradcheck to compare Jacobian matrix,

```
from torch.autograd import gradcheck
func = MyFunc.apply
input = (torch.randn(3,3,dtype=torch.double,requires_grad=True))
test = gradcheck(func, input)
```

and the result was

[image]

Please someone help me to get correct back propagation result

Thanks!

---

Q2.

Thanks for answers!

Because of your help, I could implement back propagation in case of (H,W) tensor.

However, while I implemented back propagation in case of (N,H,W) tensor, I got a problem.
I think the problem would be initializing new tensor.

Here's my new code

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class MyFunc(torch.autograd.Function):
  @staticmethod
  def forward(ctx, input):
    ctx.save_for_backward(input)
    
    N = input.size(0)
    for n in range(N):
      input[n] /= torch.sum(input[n], dim=0)

    return input

  @staticmethod
  def backward(ctx, grad_output):
    input = ctx.saved_tensors[0]
    N, H, W = input.size()
    I = torch.eye(H).unsqueeze(-1)
    sum = input.sum(1)

    grad_input = torch.zeros((N,H,W), dtype = torch.double, requires_grad=True)
    for n in range(N):
      grad_input[n] = ((sum[n] * I - input[n]) * grad_output[n] / sum[n]**2).sum(1)

    return grad_input
```

Gradcheck code is

```
from torch.autograd import gradcheck
func = MyFunc.apply
input = (torch.rand(2,2,2,dtype=torch.double,requires_grad=True))
test = gradcheck(func, input)
print(test)
```

and result is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuY6c.png)

I don't know why the error occurs...

Your help will be very helpful for me to implement my own convolutional network.

Thanks! Have a nice day.

Comment: Why do you want to implement the backward pass yourself?

Comment: @Ivan because I want to make my own convolutional network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look an example with a single column, for instance: `[[x1], [x2], [x3]]`.

Let `sum` be `x1 + x2 + x3`, then normalizing `x` will give `y = [[y1], [y2], [y3]] = [[x1/sum], [x2/sum], [x3/sum]]`. You're looking for `dL/dx1`, `dL/x2`, and `dL/x3` - we'll just write them as: `dx1`, `dx2`, and `dx3`. Same for all `dL/dyi`.

So `dx1` is equal to `dL/dy1*dy1/dx1 + dL/dy2*dy2/dx1 + dL/dy3*dy3/dx1`. That's because `x1` contributes to all ouput element on the corresponding column: `y1`, `y2`, and `y3`.

We have:

- `dy1/dx1 = d(x1/sum)/dx1 = (sum - x1)/sum²`
- `dy2/dx1 = d(x2/sum)/dx1 = -x2/sum²`
- similarly, `dy3/dx1 = d(x3/sum)/dx1 = -x3/sum²`

Therefore `dx1 = (sum - x1)/sum²*dy1 - x2/sum²*dy2 - x3/sum²*dy3`. Same for `dx2` and `dx3`. As a result, the Jacobian is `[dxi]_i = (sum - xi)/sum²` and `[dxi]_j = -xj/sum²` (for all `j` different to `i`).

**In your implementation, you seem to be missing all non-diagonal components.**

Keeping the same one-column example, with `x1=2`, `x2=3`, and `x3=5`:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[2.], [3.], [5.]])

>>> sum = input.sum(0)
tensor([10])
```

The Jacobian will be:

```
>>> J = (sum*torch.eye(input.size(0)) - input)/sum**2
tensor([[ 0.0800, -0.0200, -0.0200],
        [-0.0300,  0.0700, -0.0300],
        [-0.0500, -0.0500,  0.0500]])
```

---

For an implementation with multiple columns, it's a bit trickier, more specifically for the shape of the diagonal matrix. It's easier to keep the *column* axis last so we don't have to bother with broadcastings:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[2., 1], [3., 3], [5., 5]])
>>> sum = x.sum(0)
tensor([10.,  9.])

>>> diag = sum*torch.eye(3).unsqueeze(-1).repeat(1, 1, len(sum))
tensor([[[10.,  9.],
         [ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [10.,  9.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.],
         [10.,  9.]]])
```

Above `diag` has a shape of `(3, 3, 2)` where the two *columns* are on the last axis. Notice how we didn't need to broadcast `sum`.

What I **wouldn't** have done is: `torch.eye(3).unsqueeze(0).repeat(len(sum), 1, 1)`. Since with this kind of shape - `(2, 3, 3)` - you will have to use `sum[:, None, None]`, and will need further broadcasting down the road...

The Jacobian is simply:

```
>>> J = (diag - x)/sum**2
tensor([[[ 0.0800,  0.0988],
         [-0.0300, -0.0370],
         [-0.0500, -0.0617]],

        [[-0.0200, -0.0123],
         [ 0.0700,  0.0741],
         [-0.0500, -0.0617]],

        [[-0.0200, -0.0123],
         [-0.0300, -0.0370],
         [ 0.0500,  0.0494]]])
```

You can check the results by backpropagating through the operation using an arbitrary `dy` vector (not with `torch.ones` though, you'll get `0`s because of `J`!). After backpropagating, `x.grad` should equal to `torch.einsum('abc,bc->ac', J, dy)`.

Comment: I see you did the exercise ;) +1

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I could implement back-propagation in case of (H,W) tensor

Comment: However, I got a problem in case of (N,H,W) tensor... Although I used for loop for each tensor in the batch(N), error occurred. I'll upload my code and an image. Could you help me to get correct answer for (N,H,W) tensor case?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your Jacobian is not accurate: It is a 4d tensor, you only computed a 2D slice of it.

You neglected the second row of the Jacobian:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer for Q2.

I implemented back propagation myself for many batch case.
I used unsqueeze function and it worked.

size of input : (N,H,W) (N is batch size)

```
forward:
  out = input / torch.sum(input, dim=1).unsqueeze(1)

backward:
  diag = torch.eye(input.size(1),  dtype=torch.double, requires_grad=True).unsqueeze(-1)
  sum = input.sum(1)
  grad_input = ((sum.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(1) * diag - input.unsqueeze(1)) * grad_out.unsqueeze(1) / (sum**2).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(1)).sum(2)
```